# Has thread logic changed in ruby2.0 compared to ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, ruby-2.0

I tried an example from "Well Grounded Rubyist" book, which featured Ruby 1.9 in my Ruby 2.0
and get different results. Instead from result from book:

> Starting the thread
>
> Outside the thread

I get just a second line:

> Outside the thread

Here's code example:

```
Thread.new do 
  puts "Starting a thread"
  sleep 2
  puts "At the end of the thread"
end

puts "Outside the thread"
```

Why so?

You can see the different results here: (online ruby interpreters - first is ruby 1.9 and second is ruby 2.0)

http://www.compileonline.com/execute_ruby_online.php

http://ideone.com/XkGn2a

Comment: Works fine in Ruby 2.0's IRB.

Comment: Denis, please try not IRB, but as a standalone program, like "ruby 1.rb"

Comment: On my Ruby 2.0.0, I get the first result, as per the book. In Ruby 1.9.3 I get the second result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run it as an executable rather than IRB, you also need to make the child thread join the parent at some point. Else the child will get killed when the parent is done.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

t = Thread.new do 
  puts "Starting a thread"
  sleep 2
  puts "At the end of the thread"
  nil
end

puts "Outside the thread"

t.join
```

---

I can't reproduce different outputs on my laptop:

```
~/wk $ /usr/bin/ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin11.0]
~/wk $ /usr/local/bin/ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]
```

With `t.join`:

```
~/wk $ /usr/bin/ruby test.rb 
Starting a thread
Outside the thread
At the end of the thread
~/wk $ /usr/local/bin/ruby test.rb
Starting a thread
Outside the thread
At the end of the thread
```

Without `t.join`:

```
~/wk $ /usr/bin/ruby test.rb 
Starting a thread
Outside the thread
~/wk $ /usr/local/bin/ruby test.rb
Starting a thread
Outside the thread
```

---

I do reproduce them on my server however:

```
~ $ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [amd64-freebsd9]
```

With `t.join`:

```
~ $ ruby test.rb 
Outside the thread
Starting a thread
At the end of the thread
```

Without `t.join`:

```
~ $ ruby test.rb 
Outside the thread
```

If I add `sleep 1` towards the end of your script, however, I do get the following:

```
~ $ ruby test.rb 
Outside the thread
Starting a thread
```

As such, methinks there are no differences beyond, perhaps, cosmetic implementation details. You just need to join the parent.

In addition, of course, you should not expect any particular order for "Outside the thread" and "Starting a thread". The two run in parallel and there is no guarantee that one occurs before another.

Comment: I know about "join" method, but the problem is different - I have different output on different versions of Ruby... (in example without "join")

Comment: Nope… I've added examples in 1.8.7, 1.9.3, and 2.0. I stand by my initial explanation…

Comment: I see a difference in behaviour too, but this seems purely to be about how concurrent threads are allowed to wrap up on program exit. It's not a behaviour difference that needs to be taken into account in a well-behaved application. It is possible it could make a difference if a multi-threaded Ruby application crashes, although it is not clear what the practical consequences are.